# While statement help (PHP)

Tags: php

My database contains both questions and answers. The questions have an ID (intQAID) and the responses have an ID (intResponseID). The intRespondID is the same as the intQAID ID that it is responding to. Each entry into the database has its own ID, which is intPostID.

What's i'm trying to do is write a query that will grab all this information and post it to a website using a while statement. However, the structure needs to be Question and underneath be the answer, until the while loop ends.

I can get the questions to post:

```
$question = mysql_query("SELECT *,
(SELECT cUsername FROM tblUsers tblU WHERE Q2.intPosterID = tblU.intUserID) AS username, 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dPostDateTime, '%b %e %Y %H:%i')) AS post_time 
FROM tblQA Q2 WHERE intResponseID = 0 
ORDER BY Q2.dSortDateTime DESC, Q2.intQAID DESC LIMIT 40");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($question))
{
echo "<tr class='forum'>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . substr($row['cBody'], 0, 150) . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['cCategory'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['post_time'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

But how can I get it to post the answer in the same while statement?

Should output like so:

```
Question 1:
  Answer 1:
Question 2:
  Answer 2:
Question 3:
  Answer 3:
etc....
```

Comment: Is it always one answer per question?

Comment: please, stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions

Comment: Have you tried writing a JOIN statement to combine the question and answer data in the same query?

Comment: What's your table structure? Are answers stored in a separate table from questions? If so, you need to do a JOIN to select the appropriate answer for each question. Once that's done, you should be able to get the answer data out of your fetched array in the same way you're getting the question data.

Comment: @tereško - Sadly the Internet has a long memory and doesn't forget those out-of-date tutorials

Comment: @tereško I agree, and yet I find myself falling back on mysql to answer newbie questions because there's so much more scaffolding you have to explain before you can show someone how to do something simple with mysqli (PDO is a little better, though).

Comment: Sorry if my code isn't up to date. I'm an amateur coder trying to learn. There are multiple answers to one question, but I'm planning to pull out only answers from a specific user.

Comment: @tereško - "ancient mysql_* functions"?  I'm curious... what would you use instead?  ...absent some other CMS framework (eg. Drupal), how do you make your mysql calls?

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr , with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). The 10+ year old `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained, and even the process of deprecation has [already begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Comment: @tereško - Thanks!  (*curses under his breath*  ...great.  something new I have to learn...  ;) )

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr , this tutorial might help : http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers .. Understanding *prepared statements* would be the most important part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a JOIN statement. As long as your questions and answers are one-to-one, you should be able to pull everything in one fell swoop.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: The Questions and Answers are in the same table. The other table is user information.

Comment: You were on the right track using a table. Something like `echo '<tr><td>Question</td></tr><tr><td>' . $row['question'] . '</td></tr>'; echo '<tr><td>Answer</td></tr><tr><td>' . $row['answer'] . '</td></tr>';` should work

Answer (score 1):

Join the table on itself:

```
SELECT 
*,
(SELECT cUsername FROM tblUsers tblU WHERE Q2.intPosterID = tblU.intUserID) AS username, 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dPostDateTime, '%b %e %Y %H:%i')) AS post_time 
FROM       tblQA Q2 
JOIN       tblQA AS tblQAjoin ON tblQAjoin.intRespondID = Q2.intPostID
WHERE      Q2.intResponseID = 0   
ORDER BY   Q2.dSortDateTime DESC, Q2.intQAID DESC 
LIMIT      40
```

I'm not sure why you would want to design your table this way, though. If there can just be one answer per question, why not simply have two columns in a row, one containing the question and the other one the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If every question has only one answer, then you should get the data for both in the one query by joining the questions table with the answers table using intRespondID and intQAI.

Then each trip through the while loop has a , whatever you want on the first line, a , a , whatever you want on the second line, and finally a .  So one trip through the loop doesn't have to just show one line of output.

Comment: All posts are in a single table. SO I don't need to join. I'm more interested in how to write the while statement to write out the question and answer in the specific format

Comment: Yes, you do need to join: joining is not necessarily an operation that involves two tables. You can also join a row (in this case the question) to another row (in this case the answer) in the same table. If you put them in the same row, you won't have to join, of course. See my answer above.